# Azure SQL and Visio 2019 Plan 2 Database Reverse engineering wizard Fails

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, visio, database-diagram

[Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R1Gm.jpg)I am using Visio 2019, trying to reverse engineer a Azure SQL server. I have successfully created multiple User data sources to use in the wizard using both our DB-admin user and my admin azure directory logins. The database credentials are successfully verified and the tables/views i want to reverse engineer are about to load in when i get the following:

Visio reverse engineer database wizard raises error:

```
"Error! Cannot extract column definition for the table/view . The definition is not

available or you may not have sufficient privileges."
```

with a text box that says:

```
"Could not find server "database name"* in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers."
```

I can neither find sys.servers nor run sp.addlinkedserver as it does not exist. though, sys.sysservers does exist.

I starred database name since instead of showing the target DB of "DB_2.0" it shows "DB_2" which is not the full name of the Database.

As i mentioned above i believe that i have sufficient privileges as i have tried both the admin username and password and my admin login using azure directory. So it may have something to do with not having the sys.servers table?

Is there a way to create the sys.servers table or create the stored procedure sp.addlinkedserver as Visio is requesting? Is it advisable to do is Azure SQL, could the naming convention of our DB have anything to do with the error?

Comment: Is that you cannot load data for Azure SQL?

Comment: @JimXu it can connect to the Azure SQL and allows me to select the views/Tables i want to create an ERD for but the when it goes to read in the table and data-types it raises the above errors.

Comment: Could you please provide the screenshot  the steps when you meet the error?

Comment: @JimXu link posted

Answer (score 0):

Worked with MSFT support, they had me rename my database from DB_2.0 to DB_2. I created a new connection DSN and it worked perfectly afterwards. Apparently visio doesn't like the ".0" in a connection string. It would be nice if i could have eddited the connection string in a text file so I did not have to rename my entire DB.